# How to remove a textbox from a html website?

Tags: html, css

[image]

Hey, i am currently trying to build my first website with html.
But while i was trying to add some Text to it i noticed that there was a box with my text in and not just my text on the background. I don´t really like the looks of the box and wanted to ask how to remove it?`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>live_game</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=The+Nautigal:wght@700&family=Trispace:wght@200&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        html, body {
            
            background-color: #288BA8; 
            color: white; 
            font-size: 30px; 
            font-family: 'The Nautigal', cursive;
            font-family: 'Trispace', sans-serif;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/417173/pexels-photo-417173.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=pexels-pixabay-417173.jpg&fm=jpg");
            background-size: 100%;
        }

        textarea {
            border: none;
            background-color: transparent;
            resize: none;
            outline: none;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>My first website</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's not a textbox. That's the body of your document, to which you applied a background image. Changing `html, body` to `html` is one way to fix it

Comment: The posted image looks af there is a CSS rule for `h1` that has the same background-image as the rule for `html, body`. If yes, erase that setting.

Comment: @Johannes Yes it does. Fullscreen it.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, You are changing the style of "textarea" but do not have a `<textarea>` tag in your HTML code. So of course it will change nothing.

Secondly, and what is actually effecting your code, is the fact you are making adjustments to the `body` at the top of the style sheet. Just take `body` out, and it will run as you want.

As for your confusion with the `textarea`, you need to add an id, or class to your `<h1>` to reference it in your CSS code. Or just reference the h1 in your CSS code (though this will effect all other `<h1>` tags in your HTML).

Or you could just change the tag from `<h1>` to `<textarea>` in your HTML code.

See what was done [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp).

They created a `<textarea>` tag, which can be referenced in the style sheet (CSS), but they also created an id.

I hope this is helpful.